# Event delegation and jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to attach an event to dynamically loaded navigation items in a nav bar. When the loaded nav item is clicked, it will do something (alert "hello world"). I'm pretty sure the answer here has something to do with event delegation but I've tried a bunch of things and haven't exactly figured it out yet.

myNav to be loaded:

```
   <div id='myNav'>
        <ul>
            <li id='navItem1'>1</li>
            <li id='navItem2'>2</li>
            <li id='navItem3'>3</li>
            <li id='navItem4'>4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Is loaded into navBar:

```
<div id='navBar'>
</div>
```

Here's the js that runs it:

```
var loadURL = "index.html #myNav";
$("#navBar").load(loadURL).slideDown("medium");
```

Now attach an event to the newly loaded nav item (This is the part I'm doing wrong):

```
$('#navItem1').on("click", function(){ 
   alert("hello world!");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the delegated version of `on()`, and delegate to the element that is not dynamically inserted, in this case `#navBar`

```
$("#navBar").on("click", "#navItem1", function(){ 
   alert("hello world!");
});
```

or the callback provided in load() to attach the event handler when the elements have actually loaded

```
$("#navBar").load(loadURL, function() {
    $('#navItem1').on("click", function(){ 
        alert("hello world!");
    });
}).slideDown("medium");
```